# Nginx and angular: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx

so my problem is, that nginx is apparently not loading all the dependecies for angular defined at the beginning of the .html view.

This is an excerpt from the `start_game.html`

```
`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

    <!--<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,400italic'>-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/../node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/../app/assets/app.css"/>

    <script src="/../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/../node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="/../node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="/../node_modules/angular-environment/dist/angular-environment.js"></script>

    <script src="/../node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>


    <script>
        angular.module("startGame", ['ngMaterial']);
    </script>

    <script src="/start_game.js"></script>
`
```

The `nginx.conf` file looks like this

`server {
                # Used to set address and/or port for IP.
                listen       80;
                server_name localhost;
                include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

```
            location /console {
                    proxy_pass http://jatos-backend;
            }

            # all other traffic
            location / {
                    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                    try_files $uri /trust/start_game/start_game.html$is_args$args;
                    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            }

            location /start_game {
                    return 404;
            }

    }
```

`

When requesting `http://localhost` i get the following errors
[Console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZISmY.png)

but the actual path `http://localhost/trust/start_game/start_game.html` directly to the view resolves without any issues.

Thank you for your time

Comment: it looks like you are trying to access folder up one level from root .. no ?

Comment: Iam not sure if i got your point correctly but the absolute path to the project is /usr/share/nginx/html/trust/. In this directory resides the /node_modules folder and the /start_game folder that contains the start_game.html that should be loaded

Comment: that does not matter for browser - as there //localhost is the root. You can either change file paths in html file, or change file folder structure, so main.htm will be at root level and you'll never need to use `..`

Comment: Thats true, thanks for pointing that out. But even without the `..` it is still the same error

Comment: Error just says that you are getting html instead of js, and html is probably the default 404 page of nginx. Open F12, Network - and go look what you are hitting instead if what you want )